# Kotlin coroutine with runBlocking infinite loop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I [found](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1679) this snippet of code for an interesting case of an infinite loop (it's not a deadlock as one thread/coroutine keeps progressing) with Kotlin coroutines, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why removing the first `yield()` solves the issue?

Tried debugging it and it seems that `while (job.isActive) yield()` just schedules itself to run over and over, instead of scheduling `job` coroutine which I would be expecting.

Can someone explain why this code doesn't work, and why removing the first `yield()`fixes it?

```
    @Test
    fun testDeadlock() = runBlocking {
        val job = launch {
            runBlocking {
                println("1")
            }
            println("2")
        }

        yield() // Comment yield and test starts to pass
        runBlocking {
            println("3")
            while (job.isActive) yield()
        }
    }
```

Comment: From `runBlocking` doc: "This function should not be used from a coroutine"

Comment: Yes, it explicitly states it shouldn't be used this way, but it doesn't say why. I'm interested in understanding why the above code results in an infinite loop, rather than how to fix it.